# Parse Text with RegEx?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to Parse Values out of a Text that looks like this:

```
Description. Question?
A. First Answer
B. Second Answer
C. Third Answer

Answer: A, B
```

Now i need to find out the Description, the Question, the Answers and which Answers are correct. Is that Possible with RegEx? I know it should be possible, but I'm not an RegEx Expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously Regex is great, but once the parsing logic becomes advanced, so does the regex needed to solve the problem. I would suggest breaking up the logic into smaller pieces (i take it you have some sort of scripting language available to do some preprocessing?)

Even if you get the whole thing matched with one killer regex - changing it later (by you or some other sorry person) would be a pain.

I would match the answers with something like this (You'd need to strip the commas):

```
^Answer: (\w,?)+
```

And then I'd do logic to reparse the text with the answers found with the first regex, with something like this (rebuilding the match, in this case A was an answer):

```
^A\.\s(.*)
```

It might not be something to flash your friends with, but it will be easier to maintain, and a heck lot easier to understand.

Comment: "^A\.\s(.*)" works well, thanks! But I have a Problem. I have some Answers with line breaks. How can i Match the whole Answer without Matching the next Answer?

Comment: Oh, "^A\.\s([^B]*)" does the Job!

Comment: The newlines complicate things but you can make the regex lazy like this: \nA\.\s(.*?)\n\B\.\s

Answer (score 0):

Just about anything you could possibly want to do with parsing text is possible with Regular Expressions, you will have to invest some time to learn it though.  How tricky your particular task is depends on how consistent your body of text it. So in short, yes, but don't ask me for the Reg Ex! Good Luck.

Comment: "to invest some time to learn it though.", the only Problem is, I have no time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you could be more specific with your example and show an actual question and description it would be easier to tell for sure, but if I'm reading this right you could find all the text up to the last full stop "." before the question-mark "?", then find the text after it up to the question mark "?", and finally use the letters with full stops "." right after them, so something like this pseudo:

> lastFullStopBeforeQ = text.substring(0 to first question
>   mark).lastIndexOf(".")
>
> Description = text.substring(0 to lastFullStopBeforeQ)
>
> Question = text.substring(lastFullStopBeforeQ+1 to first question
>   mark)
>
> Answers[0] = text.substring(first question mark+1 to next "\n") ...
>
> CorrectAnswers[0] = text.substring(next index of "Answer:" to next
>   ",") ...

I know this is possible using C#, if you use something else then i can't give you a clear answer.